# Lambda : Send a message to SQS

Tags: lambda, stripe-payments, amazon-sqs

I tried to upgrade one of my lambda but can't make it work... 
so I have a lambda to manage my stripe payment, everything work fine.

I want to send a message to SQS when a payment is OK.

You can see my lambda function below :

```
const stripe = require('stripe')("sk_test_xXxXxXxXxX");
const ApiBuilder = require('claudia-api-builder');
const querystring = require('querystring');
var api = new ApiBuilder();

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sqs = new AWS.SQS({region : 'eu-west-1'});
var queueUrl = 'https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xXXxXXxXXx/xXxXxX-new-site.fifo';



api.post('/stripe',request => {
    console.log(request);
    let params = querystring.parse(request.body);
    console.log(params);

    return stripe.charges.create({
      amount: params.package,
      currency: 'eur',
      description: `12 month charge`,
      source: params.stripeToken,
      receipt_email: params.email,
      metadata: {domain_name: params.domain_name, email: params.email},
    }).then(charge => {
        var responseBody = {
            message: ''
        };

        var responseCode = 200;

        var message = {
            MessageBody: "TEST",
            QueueUrl: queueUrl
        };
        console.log(message);

        sqs.sendMessage(message, function(err, data) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(data);

            if (err) {
                console.log('error:', "failed to send message" + err);
                var responseCode = 500;
            } else {
                console.log('data:', data.MessageId);
                responseBody.message = 'Sent to ' + queueUrl;
                responseBody.messageId = data.MessageId;
            }
            var response = {
                statusCode: responseCode,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(responseBody)
            };

            return response;
        });
      return charge;
    }).catch((err) => {
        return err;
    });
});

module.exports = api;
```

I added the code betweend line 25 and 59.

On cloudwatch logs I can see the console output from line 36 (        console.log(message);) but nothing from the line 39.

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so experienced in AWS Lambda, but I see that you execute async code with callback (sqs.sendMessage()) and immediately call `return charge` without awaiting of result of such execution (sqs.sendMessage())

I'm not pretty sure about what Lambda should return (probably, `response`, not `charge`), but if you want to see your `console.log` results inside `sqs.sendMessage()` call, the code might look something like this:

```
    // above code ommitted
}).then(async charge => {
        //code ommitted
        console.log(message);
// if Lambda supports async/await OR return this promise and process it in next chain
        await sqs.sendMessage(message)
             .promise()
             .then(data=>{
             // process data here
             })
             .catch(err=>{
             // process error here
             })
      return charge;
    }).catch((err) => {
        return err;
    });
});
```