# How to insert when sending a message to SQS via lambda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, aws-lambda

I am trying to send a message to SQS queue using Lambda:

Here is my code:

```
var QUEUE_URL = 'https://us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com/123456789/ntech-event-processing-dev.fifo';
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sqs = new AWS.SQS({region : 'us-west-2'});

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  var params = {
    MessageBody: JSON.stringify(event),
    QueueUrl: QUEUE_URL
  };
  sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err,data){
    if(err) {
      console.log('error:',"Fail Send Message" + err);
      context.done('error', "ERROR Put SQS");  // ERROR with message
    }else{
      console.log('data:',data.MessageId);
      context.done(null,'');  // SUCCESS 
    }
  });
}
```

Here is my test data (JSON), notice I have defined MessageGroupId there.

```
{
  "MessageGroupId": "1",
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
2020-04-16T17:40:37.604Z    fa709a07-0bcd-4b17-a48b-341a984aec88    INFO    error: Fail Send MessageMissingParameter: The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId.
2020-04-16T17:40:37.661Z    fa709a07-0bcd-4b17-a48b-341a984aec88    ERROR   Invoke Error    {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"error","stack":["Error: error","    at _homogeneousError (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:13:12)","    at postError (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:30:54)","    at done (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:57:7)","    at Object.done (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:105:16)","    at Response.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:13:15)","    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:364:18)","    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)","    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)","    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)","    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)"]}
```

I have looked at:
[Lambda : Send a message to SQS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642942/lambda-send-a-message-to-sqs) AND
[Lambda can't send message to SQS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58501450/lambda-cant-send-message-to-sqs)
But I did not find an answer.

Any help is apprecaited!

Comment: remove `MessageGroupId` from event. your `MessageGroupId` is going under `MessageBody`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look in documentation of [SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html) you can see that:

> MessageGroupId - This parameter applies only to FIFO
>   (first-in-first-out) queues.

I assume that you have accidentally created FIFO queue on SQS. So you need that additional parameter. You could modify your code like this:

```
var QUEUE_URL = 'https://us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com/123456789/ntech-event-processing-dev.fifo';
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sqs = new AWS.SQS({region : 'us-west-2'});

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  var params = {
    MessageBody: JSON.stringify(event),
    QueueUrl: QUEUE_URL,
    MessageGroupId: "TestGroup"
  };
  sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err,data){
    if(err) {
      console.log('error:',"Fail Send Message" + err);
      context.done('error', "ERROR Put SQS");  // ERROR with message
    }else{
      console.log('data:',data.MessageId);
      context.done(null,'');  // SUCCESS 
    }
  });
}
```

It doesn't help if you putt your MessageGroupId into event if you didn't take from your event. If you want to receive MessageGroupId from event could could look like this:

```
var QUEUE_URL = 'https://us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com/123456789/ntech-event-processing-dev.fifo';
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sqs = new AWS.SQS({region : 'us-west-2'});

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  var params = {
    MessageBody: JSON.stringify(event),
    QueueUrl: QUEUE_URL,
    MessageGroupId: event.MessageGroupId
  };
  sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err,data){
    if(err) {
      console.log('error:',"Fail Send Message" + err);
      context.done('error', "ERROR Put SQS");  // ERROR with message
    }else{
      console.log('data:',data.MessageId);
      context.done(null,'');  // SUCCESS 
    }
  });
}
```

Tutorial that I have found useful is this [one](https://stackabuse.com/message-queueing-in-node-js-with-aws-sqs/).